# Quantifier String Placement

Tags: algorithms, logic, satisfiability

This is the edited question:

Suppose I have $(x_1 \vee y_1 \vee y_2)$. x is existential and y is universal. Then it should be like this in the quantifier string: $\forall y_1 \forall y_2 \exists x_1$   (WHY?)

Now suppose I introduce a new variable z and convert the above clause to: $(x_1 \vee \neg z  \vee y_2 ) \land (z \vee x_2)$. My question is where should I insert z in the quantifier string and with which quantifier(exisential or universal)?

Also, don't reply saying that you can place it anywhere...because the position of insertion does matter.

Thank you

Comment: That depends on what you want to express.

Comment: The question still doesn't make sense. Where you put the quantifier depends on what you're trying to express. I'm not trying to be rude or nasty but it seems that there's something fundamental that you don't understand. If I could work out what it was, I'd try to explain it to you. I also can't work out why you're fixated on the idea of adding variables to an existing formula. Everything to do with the formula is determined by what the formula is, not the order in which things were added. (E.g., "John is happy" means the same thing even if I write "is happy" and then add "John" before it.)

Comment: Ok.. so is it fine with you if I use $\exists x_1 \forall y_1 \forall y_2$ as a quantifier string for $(x_1 \vee y_1 \vee y_2)$?

Comment: I am trying to express this as a 2 player game: Existential and Universal players

Comment: I don't know. I **can't** know. You *could* use that quantifier string. You *could* use any other one. Which is correct depends on what you're trying to say. It's like asking "Is it fine if I use $n=27$?" How am I supposed to know? I don't know what property you're trying to express. If $n$ is supposed to represent the fingers on my hand then, no, it's not fine if you choose $n=27$. If $n$ is supposed to represent the cube of three then, yes, it's fine if you choose $n=27$. If $n$ is supposed to represent something else, maybe it's fine and maybe it isn't.

Comment: I told you that I am trying to express it as a 2 player game:   Let X denote the existential player and Y denote the universal player. And The expression is true if existential player wins. and false if Universal player wins\

Answer (score 1):

If, as I suspect, you are [still trying to convert quantified 3-CNF formulas into quantified mixed Horn formulas](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/26281/np-hard-mixed-q-horn-sat), the answer is that quantifiers for the newly added bridge variables can be placed anywhere in the quantifier list.  This is because their final values are completely contingent on the setting of all other variables in the formula, so you will *always* be able to set them to correct values to satisfy the formula if the formula is satisfiable.

Comment: I talked about it with my professor, he said you have take all the cases and look where putting in satisfies. You cannot insert anywhere.